# Typescript compiled Javascript Code is not working (variable.default.function())

Tags: javascript, typescript

The Problem is that the js generated from home.ts doesn't find my index.js class. I got no errors in Typescript but I got one when I run the javascript.

> TypeError: index_1.default.login is not a function
>       at /Users/Jannik/Documents/Web/Willhub-ts/dist/controllers/home.js:12:37
>       at Object. (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Web/Willhub-ts/dist/controllers/home.js:15:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object. (/Users/Jannik/Documents/Web/Willhub-ts/dist/app.js:20:24)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)

Any idea where this could come from?

Home.ts:

```
router.get('/', Index.login());
router.get('/', Index.index());
```

Home.js:

```
router.get('/', index_1.default.login());
router.get('/', index_1.default.index());
```

Index.ts

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';


export default class Index {
private static _index: Function;
private static _login: Function;

constructor(){
    this.constructIndex();
    this.constructLogin();
}

//Private Methods:
private constructIndex(): void {
    Index._index = function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {

        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true })
        next();
    }
}

private constructLogin(): void {
    Index._index = function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true })
        const isLoggedIn: boolean = true;
    }
}

//Public Methods:
public static get index() : Function {
    return this._index;
}

public static get login(): Function {
    return this._login;
}

}
```

Index.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });


class Index {
constructor() {
    this.constructIndex();
    this.constructLogin();
}
//Private Methods:
constructIndex() {
    Index._index = function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true });
        next();
    };
}
constructLogin() {
    Index._index = function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true });
        const isLoggedIn = true;
    };
}
//Public Methods:
static get index() {
    return this._index;
}
static get login() {
    return this._login;
}
}
exports.default = Index;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `constructLogin()` is probably wrong since it should be assigning `Index._login` I guess:

```js
private constructLogin(): void {
    // -----\/------------------
    Index._index = function (req: Request, res: Response, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true })
        const isLoggedIn: boolean = true;
    }
}
```

If you fix that, check whether you use `Index.login()` before creating an instance first. That's because:

- `Index.login` is a getter function that returns `Index._login`
- `Index.login()` invokes the resulting `Index._login`, but...
- `Index._login` is set in `constructLogin()`, and...
- `constructLogin()` is called in the `constructor()` function

If you invoke `Index.login()` before creating an instance, `Index._login` would be `undefined`:

```js
class Index {
constructor() {
    this.constructIndex();
    this.constructLogin();
}
//Private Methods:
constructIndex() {
    Index._index = function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true });
        next();
    };
}
constructLogin() {
    // NOTICE: Assigns `_login` instead
    Index._login = function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("main", { "header-enabled": true, "nav-enabled": true });
        const isLoggedIn = true;
    };
}
//Public Methods:
static get index() {
    return this._index;
}
static get login() {
    return this._login;
}
}

console.log(Index._login); // undefined

let i = new Index();

console.log(Index._login); // function
```